# CSS consistent top/bottom padding in a box

Tags: css

I want to create a box with consistent spacing on all sides, regardless of the content.

Unfortunately, elements have margins which cause issues when the box is given padding. This is expected because the element's margin doesn't 'flow' out of the box over padding. A demo is at http://jsfiddle.net/cZf7E/1/

Up to now I've had special style rules for anything in the box which is at the top (with `margin-top: 0`) and bottom (with `margin-bottom: 0`). For the top it's not bad, but at the bottom there's a lot of potential tags to style.

Is there a way to do this that's not so hacky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
aside :first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
​aside :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}​
```

First/ last element can be any kind of element (`h1`, `h2`, ..., `p`, `div`, `span`)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/cZf7E/4/)

Note that there is a space between `aside` and [**`first-child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3afirst-child)/ [**`last-child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3alast-child). Without it, the styling would apply to the first/ last `aside`.

---

If there will be more levels in the `aside` and propagation further down is not desirable, it is better to use

```
aside > :first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
​aside > :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}​
```

in order to select just the direct children of the `aside`.

[Propagation vs. no propagation demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/cZf7E/5/) (of course, `margin` won't apply to inline elements such as `span`, `em`, or `strong` - it was just to show how propagation works.)

---

**Support**: As Ben Dyer has pointed out, `last-child` is a [**CSS3 pseudo-class**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/). It is not supported by IE8 or older. Also, `first-child` is buggy in IE8 and 7.

Comment: Only thing to note about this solution is that `:last-child` won't work with anything before IE9. `:first-child` can work with IE7 and IE8, but it has some quirky behaviors. This is the most elegant solution, but if you need full browser support, you're probably stuck with hacky solutions. Good browsers will have full support of these selectors though.

Comment: Browser support is an issue, but more and more I can let small things visually degrade. Thanks Ana, I thought something would've come along (with fairly good browser support) since I started using CSS!

Is there any advantage/disadvantage to using `aside :first-child` vs `aside>:first-child` - parser efficiency?

Comment: Actually, it's better specifying `aside > :first-child` to stop propagation to the children of the children... of the `aside` - I didn't take into account the fact that you might have more levels in the `aside`.

Comment: I'd say that they're a very different CSS statement. The second is valid only for direct children of aside. The other one is valid for every first child that has aside in its ancestors.